# Preventing direct download in wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website. In the blogs, there can be links to the uploaded files. Currently even if the user is not logged in, he can click the link and download the file. I want to make the user login to the website on clicking the link. Once he logs in he should be able to download the file.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm surprised not more people have commented. Anyway, you can't do this out of the box, you'll need to either use a plugin, or code ityourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple `is_user_logged_in()` function for this to change the destination of the link from the file to a dialog box or something else.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Or if you want to have some kind of user management, then you'll need to look at a file management plugin to work with your Wordpress Users.